# How does t-mobile's secureauthentication Twitter app work?

Tags: authentication

If you try to get support from T-Mobile using Twitter, they'll try to get you to allow an app that only has permission to view your tweets and your followers. How does this help T-Mobile authenticate you?

tmobile.secureauthentication.com

This application will be able to:
Read Tweets from your timeline.
See who you follow.

Will not be able to:
Follow new people.
Update your profile.
Post Tweets for you.
Access your direct messages.
See your Twitter password.

Comment: I don't understand how that helps, or what the mystery app actually does if indeed it only does what it claims. Anyone on the planet can already see my public tweets & follow list.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard OAuth flow that third-party applications use to allow Twitter accounts to log into their site, and optionally have write access to the account, though in this case T-Mobile hasn't requested this permission as they have no good reason to.

What T-Mobile is most likely doing is that they use this to make sure you are the owner of the Twitter account (as opposed to just sending a link via direct messages which can be seen by anyone if it accidentally leaks) and finally associate the Twitter account with your T-Mobile user model in their CRM system.

Answer (score -1):

If you follow the instructions, you'll get a page on API.twitter.com that asks you to enter your Twitter credentials to enable the app. Once done you're taken to a page on tmobile.secureauthentication.com that asks for name, phone number, and one of PIN/password/SSN4.

Since you'll typically be dealing with T-Mobile using DMs on Twitter, this process allows t-mobile to associate your Twitter account with your t-mobile account without putting the sensitive info (pin/pwd/ssn4) in to DMs.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question